# Writing queries to find dependencies on cards in ADO

Tags: azure-devops

I am managing a board in Azure Devops and have dependencies on tasks and stories. I cannot see the dependencies on the task board, I have to get into each card to see if they have a dependency. This is very inefficient.

My work around is to put a tag on a work item for 'Dep', create the rule, then I can see the colored card, but this is a lot of administration.

How can I write a query that looks for cards that have either a Predecessor or Successor dependency and then turn those cards a color?

i.e.:

```
Iteration path=x;
Work item type=user story or task;
Dependency=successor or predecessor;

    If successor, turn card color green
```

Answer (score 0):

> > How can I write a query that looks for cards that have either a Predecessor or Successor dependency and then turn those cards a color?

Currently there are no such queries can implement this, and your work item rule can make this partially.

In the meanwhile, there is a suggestion ticket about this here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/632131/visualization-of-work-item-dependencies-on-a-board.html, so Azure DevOps brings this extension: [Dependency Tracker extension](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmarketplace.visualstudio.com%2Fitems%3FitemName%3Dms-eswm.dependencytracker&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cf4ed0de8b4e9428c842a08d8c1a2a0a6%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637472251507216218%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=YEV%2FyiejxVsi3EkBb9Rw2L9WluHOcWyXxdZ907JUp8I%3D&reserved=0), which provides you with the ability to plan and manage dependencies across teams, projects, and organizations.

This extension provides filterable views to show all dependencies a team is consuming and producing. See: [Plan and track dependencies using the Dependency Tracker](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Fextensions%2Fdependency-tracker%3Fview%3Dazure-devops&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7Cf4ed0de8b4e9428c842a08d8c1a2a0a6%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637472251507216218%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=plNPxD6xEb38L2r4gPSaWAiHSySICqkYRaYw31kS8i8%3D&reserved=0) for details. Thus we suggest that you could use this extension to manage dependencies.

Comment: @Spencer If my answer helps, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.